# WARNING [path] bad path element ".m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar": no such file or directory

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I've decided it's time to upgrade from Java 8 to Java 11. So I've read few tutorials and made the changes in our build.

I wanted to upgrade to

```
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

currently I'm using

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_222-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

I also have

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T20:41:47+02:00)
Maven home: /usr/lib/maven/3.6.0
Java version: 11.0.4, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11.0.4.11-adoptopenjdk
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-55-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Everything looks like it works, but there was a warning in compilation, because of `error_prone_core`

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ core ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 324 source files to /srv/core/target/test-classes
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.errorprone.bugpatterns.FutureReturnValueIgnored (file:/var/cache/maven/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_core/2.3.3/error_prone_core-2.3.3.jar) to field com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$StructuralTypeMapping$4.this$0
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.errorprone.bugpatterns.FutureReturnValueIgnored
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

I've tried fixing the warning by adding the following

```xml
<arg>-J--illegal-access=debug</arg>
<arg>-J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
<arg>-J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
<arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
```

but nothing happened... so I've figured I probably need to add `<fork>true</fork>`... so I've made sure i have the correct `JAVA_HOME` configured for maven and tried with the fork... but now some modules fail the build with this warning...

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] [path] bad path element "/home/fprochazka/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar": no such file or directory
[WARNING] [path] bad path element "/home/fprochazka/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar": no such file or directory
[WARNING] [path] bad path element "/home/fprochazka/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar": no such file or directory
[WARNING] [path] bad path element "/home/fprochazka/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar": no such file or directory
[WARNING] [path] bad path element "/home/fprochazka/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar": no such file or directory
[WARNING] [path] bad path element "/home/fprochazka/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar": no such file or directory
[INFO] 6 warnings
```

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.0.M5 `spring-boot-dependencies` with very few additional version definitions. According to the `mvn dependency:tree`, the `jaxb-runtime` is imported because of hibernate

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.25.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |     \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
```

I've tried reverting to Java 8 and first resolving the problem there. This is the complete maven compiler config... And it also starts generating the warnings, if I add `<fork>true</fork>`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration combine.self="append">
        <compilerId>javac-with-errorprone</compilerId>
        <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        <source>8</source>
        <target>8</target>
        <compilerArgs combine.self="override">
            <arg>-Werror</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:all,-fallthrough,-processing,-serial,-classfile</arg>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
            <arg>-XDcompilePolicy=simple</arg>
            <arg>-XepDisableWarningsInGeneratedCode</arg>
            <arg>-XepOpt:Immutable:KnownImmutable=javax.money.CurrencyUnit</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:ConstantField:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:ClassName:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:DivZero:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:EmptyIf:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:IterablePathParameter:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:LongLiteralLowerCaseSuffix:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:AnnotationPosition:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:EmptyTopLevelDeclaration:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:EqualsBrokenForNull:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:FunctionalInterfaceClash:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:InvalidInlineTag:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:InvalidParam:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:MissingDefault:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:NonCanonicalStaticMemberImport:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:PrimitiveArrayPassedToVarargsMethod:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:RedundantOverride:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:RedundantThrows:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:StaticQualifiedUsingExpression:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:StringEquality:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:UnusedException:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:ConstantField:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:MultiVariableDeclaration:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:MultipleTopLevelClasses:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:MultipleUnaryOperatorsInMethodCall:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:PrivateConstructorForUtilityClass:WARN</arg>
            <arg>-Xep:UngroupedOverloads:WARN</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <annotationProcessorPaths combine.self="append"/>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac-errorprone</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
            <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Also, if I start locally the correctly working version of our application, this line is logged by Spring. It is not logged on production server, as there is no `restartedMain` thread, which is present only on local machine, where devtools is present. I believe it is related.

```
16:48:22.397 [restartedMain  ] INFO       o.s.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls: The Class-Path manifest attribute in /home/fprochazka/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/home/fprochazka/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/home/fprochazka/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/home/fprochazka/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/home/fprochazka/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/home/fprochazka/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/home/fprochazka/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
```

My guess is that the `jaxb-runtime` is broken in a way, that references non-existent JARs, but because the classes are available, it still works.

I have no idea how to fix this or where to report such bug. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: prueba lo que yo hice. Te puede ayudar en parte tu problema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/490183/error-en-libreria-jaxb-api-jar-de-glassfish-4-1-1